# How to have different rules for the same target depending on the input extension?

Tags: makefile

I want to use *make* to convert images into the right format for a book I'm writing. Input images are in the `figure` directory and can have different file formats, e.g. PNG, SVG or JPG. Depending on the file extension, I want to run a different conversion command. The results should land in `output` and always be of type PNG.

```
FIGURES := $(patsubst figure/%.svg,output/%.png,$(wildcard figure/*.svg))

figures: $(FIGURES)

output/%.png: figure/%.svg
    convert -density 600 -background none -resize 2500x $< $@
```

This is what I have so far, it works for SVG inputs only. How can I collect all files from the `figure` directory regardless of the file extension and apply different rules depending on the file extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
sources := $(wildcard $(addprefix figure/*,.png .svg .jpg))
targets := $(patsubst figure/%, output/%.png, $(basename $(sources)))

.PHONY: all
all: $(targets)

output/%.png: figure/%.png
    # whatever
output/%.png: figure/%.svg
    convert -density 600 -background none -resize 2500x $< $@
output/%.png: figure/%.jpg
    # blah
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this already works for me. Is it possible to supported images nested in subfolders of `figure` as well?

Comment: @danijar Sure, just change the wildcard pattern.

Comment: How would I do that to glob the files of any nesting depth within that folder?

Comment: @danijar Search for "gnu make recursive wildcard", it's been answered many times before.